# Como manipular printf em linguagem C

Tags: c, printf

Olá!

Como faço para colocar algo após a variável em um printf.
Ex:

```
printf("Digite um valor para a posição: [%d", l); printf(" ,%d", c); printf(" ]");
```

estou usando o exemplo acima, mas eu queria saber se é possível fazer algo semelhante ao pseudocódigo:
Ex:

```
printf("Digite um valor para a posição: [%d", l, ",", c, " ]");
```

O resultado final seria algo do tipo:

Digite um valor para a posição [ x, y]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main() 
{  
    int x=5;  
    int y=3;  
    printf("Digite um valor para a posição [%d, %d]", x, y);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Como ficou:

Digite um valor para a posição `[5, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, y;

    printf("Digite dois valores para definir a posição [x, y]\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("Posição escolhida [%d , %d].", x , y);

  return 0;
}
```